# Merging a remote branch into my local branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I've been told to merge **remotes/origin/robbranch into my local branch carlbranch**. How do I achieve this ? The branch to be merged from is at remote. I dont have it on my machine yet.

Answer (score 0):

to merge a remote branch you can follow these steps:

1.first bring in the changes (if any)

```
$ git fetch origin
```

2.Then you create a new local branch that's setup to track the branch robbranch in your remote repository

```
$ git checkout -b robbranch origin/robbranch
```

3.Now you go to your local carlbranch branch

```
$ git checkout carlbranch
```

4.Merge with robbranch

```
$ git merge robbranch
```

And you should be alright with that (unless there are some merge conflicts that you'll have to solve before the merge can be completed).

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step by step.

1.Add remote (remote_git: Use any name you want) to your local git directory. [Adding Remote Github help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote)

```
git remote add remote_git url
```

2.Checkout to your branch in which you want to merge

```
git checkout carlbranch
```

3.Pull robbranch and merge it in carlbranch

```
git pull -u remote_git robbranch
```

In your case, I think remote_git is your origin So you may skip Point#1 and just follow 2 and 3 with git_remote=origin